# SQL Server: How to I filter out results based on a multi-column set from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table

```
               TravelCode  Country1 Country2
                  100        USA      USA
                  100        USA      GBR
                  100        MEX      USA
                  200        CAN      USA`
```

I need to filter out results in my larger result set based on a TravelCode, Country1 and Country2.

So for:

TravelCode 100,

1) no records in my result set should have Country1 as USA (and Country2 as USA and GBR),

2) and Country1 as MEX (and Country2 as USA).

I have tried the `NOT EXISTS` approach but that does not seem to be working.

```
-- query for the larger result set with WHERE as below
-- #EXCEPTIONS temp table has the columns TravelCode,  Country1, Country2
-- these columns also exists in the larger result set temp table #BASE1
FROM #BASE4 T1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT T2.TravelCode, T2.Country1, T2.Country2
                        FROM #EXCEPTIONS T2 
                        WHERE T1.TravelCode = @travelcode -- variable containing travel code to be filtered
                               AND T1.Country1 = T2.Country1
                               AND T1.Country2 = T2.Country2)
```

Answer (score 0):

try like below

```
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                        FROM #EXCEPTIONS T2 
                        WHERE T2.TravelCode = @travelcode 

                              T2.Country1 ='MEX'
                              and T2.Country2 ='USA'
                              having count(distinct T2.Country1)=1
                                    and count(distinct T2.Country2)=1
                               )
```

Comment: Is this possible without hard coded Country1 and Country2 values ?. This maybe will not work for other TravelCode values

Comment: @sunny share sample data and output that will helpful to fix the condition

Comment: again, this will not work for TravelCode=200  (pls refer the table example I mentioned in the question)